# how can I delete yarn completely?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> I don't know why my yarn is appearing all these problems. I could not uninstall it. Every time I uninstall it and reinstall , it always kind of taking what I deleted previously .How can I avoid all these errors and get a workable yarn?

[image]

Comment: What command do you run when you get these errors? Looks like you didn't install your dependencies...

Comment: Did you try `npm uninstall -g yarn` and then removing any existing yarn folders? -> on windows: _Program Files (x86)\Yarn_

Comment: Jordi I run just yarn. When I first use yarn, it did come with a dependencies. After that,I accidentally deleted part of the files and it becomes like this.

Comment: iLuvLogix yeah bro I tried that.However, when I try to reinstall yarn , it is just getting back what I have deleted earlier on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply run

**npm uninstall -g yarn** to uninstall the yarn from your dependencies

and then run

**npm cache clean --force**

to clean the cache and then try

Comment: Should I run it on cmd or terminal in vs code?

Comment: You can try it in Cmd or Vscode.I would suggest CMD

Comment: if it worked give it a thumbs up so it can help others to. @CopperCleric